# Libgdx and ParticleEffect with scene2d not showing the same way as in the Particle Editor

Tags: libgdx, graphic-effects

I am developing a new game with libgdx and trying to implement ParticleEffect in scene2d (using actor). I am creating a ParticleEffect with Particle Editor in which I would like to 
add to a stage.

From some reason, the effect appears horizontally only (objects appear from left to right but not up and down) and is not appearing the same as in the Particle Editor (X and Y axis).
Does anyone have an idea what could be the reason for that?

**Snapshot of the horizontal effects (desktop run):**

[image: Snapshot of the horizontal effects - desktop]

**Particle Editor effect:**

[image: Particle Editor effect]

Comment: Are you subclassing `Actor` for you particle effect? If so, could you please post the implementation of the `draw(batch, parentAlpha)` method in your subclass?

Comment: public void act(float delta) {
     
       super.act(delta);
       effect.setPosition(getX(), getY());
       effect.update(delta); //update it      

       if(effect.isComplete()){
        effect.start();
       }
       
       
    }